# Textarea loses focus while typing when inside a modal?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, styled-components

I have a textarea and modal I created using styled-components. When I type in one letter in the textarea loses focus.I'm not sure if my css is the issue or if it's how I'm rendering it. It works normally when it's not in the modal.

In my render

```
    <ModalMessage show={this.state.showRejectModal}
                          onClose={() => this.setState({showRejectModal: false})}
                          content={[<p key={'rejectionMessage'}>Are you sure you want to reject?</p>,
                              <TextArea key={1}
                                     type={'text'}
                                        onChange={(e) => this.setState({reasonForRejection: e.target.value})}
                                        name={'reasonForRejection'}
                                        placeholder={'Reason for rejection'}
                                        value={this.state.reasonForRejection || ''}/>]}/>
```

Modal Component which is taking in the textarea as props.content

```
const ModalMessage = (props) => {

    const ModalWrapper = styled.div`
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: auto; 
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    `;

    const ModalContent = styled.div`
    background-color: ${modalBackgroundColor};
    margin: 15% auto; 
    padding: 20px;
    //border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 30%;
    `;

    const ModalCloseButton = styled.span`
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;

    :hover, focus{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    `;

    const HideScroll = createGlobalStyle`
    body{
        overflow: hidden;    
    }
    `;

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {props.show ? <ModalWrapper>
                <ModalContent>
                    <HideScroll/>
                    {props.noClose ? null : <ModalCloseButton onClick={props.onClose}>&times;</ModalCloseButton>}
                    {props.cancel ? <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMinusCircle} size='6x' style={{color: '#96aff5'}}/> :
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheckCircle} size='6x' style={{color: '#96aff5'}}/>}<br/>
                    {props.content}
                </ModalContent>
            </ModalWrapper> : null}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

The textarea

```
export const TextArea = styled.textarea`
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 7px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    background: transparent;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font: 16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 45px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 2px;
    color: #808080;

    ::placeholder {
       color: #808080;
       opacity: 1;
    }
    `;
```

Comment: the issue is probably the `key`. I've answered other questions where the input loses the cursor while typing.. its related to the `key`. Essentially the element gets removed and then replaced every render cycle, which is why you would lose focus. This happens when the key changes frequently. Try to give each textarea you are rendering a specific unique identifier, and reference that as the key.

Comment: @JohnRuddell Thanks for the response! I have the key value set to 1 when rendering in the top example and not other elements have the key={1}. Is using that as a key inappropriate? I tried changing it to other unique values but still had the same issue.

Comment: Could you replicate the issue on a codesandbox or something so I can take a look? I would probably put the key to something like `key="rejection-modal-textarea"`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this is what causes your issue, but I've had similar problems with inputs from setting a `value` on the element. I was able to solve my issues by changing `value` to `defaultValue`.  Using `value` on elements can have unexpected results.

Comment: Could you solve that error? I'm facing the same issue